# Populate default value to a cell based on another cell content

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

We use a spreadsheet as our time cards. The template is stored in a server with links to it on the individual's desktops.

I am trying to figure out VB code that would help in achieving the flliwing: when the cell for username (B5) is blank, the code will populate next Sunday's date in (B7). After the user enters their name in B5, the value of B7 should not be changed changed.

If I use formula (`=IF(B5="",TODAY()+8-WEEKDAY(TODAY()),B7)`) in B7, I need to enable the circular reference, which doesn't follow the template of the spreadsheet, thus causing errors for every individual.

Corporate says that the worksheet needs to be in Excel, because of the import software. Otherwise, I'd use Word and use "CreateDate" function to achieve the same.

I've been trying to learn VB to do it, but I was hoping that some expert could help out the code in 5 min. flat and just let me dissect it.

Comment: So initially when you open the spreadsheet first time - all the cells in the B7 column will have next Sundays' date. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the procedure [Auto_Open](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/running-a-macro-when-excel-starts-HA001034628.aspx), which is automatically executed every time a workbook opens. Start the VBA editor (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>), inset a new VBA module and copy-past the code below. Safe it and you're good to go.

The code looks pretty much like the formula you already had:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
    Const Sheetname = "Sheet1"
    Const NameCell = "B5"
    Const DateCell = "B7"

    If IsEmpty(Worksheets(Sheetname).Range(NameCell).Value) Then
        Worksheets(Sheetname).Range(DateCell).Value = Date + 8 - Weekday(Date)
    End If
End Sub
```